# Direct fragment parameter setting instead of passing arguments

Tags: android

I know Bundle and setArguments must be used to pass data to a fragment, but the problem is that I want a String in fragment before onCreate is called. In constructor getArguments return null. So I can't use arguments. I use this string as the title in fragmentAdaptor which get it after fragment is instantiated but before it's created.

I wonder what might happen if I set a fragment property directly when it's instantiated like this:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setTitle("title");
```

Here I don't use argument and it works very well even with config change. But I recall a scenario which something like this caused a lot of problems, although I don't remember the exact case. Maybe I was setting a more complex data structure than a String.

So my question is why must arguments be used when it's possible to set data directly and it's easier? and when direct parameter setting may cause problem?